# Conditional rendering mapped routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to conditional render mapping inside a switch.

```
Routes.js

  <Switch>
    {routeConfig.isSecureRoute === true ? 
      {routeConfig.map((route) => (
        <SecureRoute key={route} {...route} />
      ))}
    :
      {routeConfig.map((route) => (
        <Route key={route} {...route} />
      ))}
    }
  </Switch>
```

routeConfig is an array of objects with a value of `isSecureRoute: true/false`

```
routeConfig.js

const routeConfig = [
 {
   path: "/home",
   component: Home,
   exact: true,
   isSecureRoute: true
 },
 (...)
]
```

I am getting parsing errors:

[code_error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEQ72.png)

Not sure how to set up my mapping correctly. Please help, thank you in advanced!! Also, I'm fairly new to react so a detailed response or code example would be much appreciated :)

Comment: show full `routeConfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this,

```
<Switch>
    {routeConfig.map((route, index) => {
          return route.isSecureRoute === true ? (
            <Route key={index} {...route} />
          ) : (
            <Route key={index} {...route} />
          )
        })
    }
  </Switch>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response! I tried your solution but I am still receiving a parsing error in ```{route.isSecureRoute === true}``` error is: ```Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," ``` Any thoughts?

Comment: It worked! Can you please explain how adding the return fixed the error?

Comment: Here we used arrow function, as calling normal function returns some value and we need to write `return someValue` at the end of function, same way we need to return from arrow function. To learn more about arrow function see this - https://codeburst.io/javascript-understand-arrow-function-syntax-ab4081bba85b

Comment: You can skip return using `Implicit return` - https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/

Comment: Ahh I see, I see. Thanks again for the help!!